# AngularJs: stateful client-side routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

Here is the demo I have created for asking this question and the inline code as requested: http://jsfiddle.net/Gncja/1/

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='root.html'>
  <list template-id='sidebar.templateId' selected-item-id='sidebar.selectedItemId'></list>
</script>


<script type='text/ng-template' id='sidebar.html'>
<ul style='width:100%;' class='nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav'>
  <li ng-repeat='item in data' ng-class="{active:item.id==selectedItemId}">
    <a ng-href='#/{{item.id}}'>
      <i class=icon-chevron-right></i>
      <span ng-bind='item.text'></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>    
</script>

<body ng-app='main'>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>​

function RootCtrl($scope, $routeParams){
  $scope.sidebar = {
    templateId: 'sidebar',
    selectedItemId: $routeParams.navItemId
  };
}

RootCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$routeParams'];

angular.module('main', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
      when('/:navItemId', {
        templateUrl: 'root.html',   
        controller: RootCtrl
      }).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/1'});
}]).
directive('list', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
      'templateId': '=',
      'selectedItemId':'='
    }, 
    template:'<ng-include src="templateUrl"></ng-include>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
      $scope.templateUrl = $scope.templateId + '.html';
      $scope.data = [
          {'id':'1', text:'lorem ipsum'},
          {'id':'2', text:'dolor sit amet'},
          ];

    }
  };
});​
```

This is a small piece of the application I have been working on, but it clearly shows what it is doing. There is the navigation menu in the page, the menu item is a link to the hash that is handled by angular.js routing that initializes the root controller, etc., it's quite tricky to describe, but the code sample clearly shows it.
The problem the entire page content is re-rendered each time when I click the navigation menu item - the routing is stateless and it does know nothing about the previous state. I would like to avoid this by re-using the navigation menu data/template rendering result when a user just navigates between the menu items(or browser history). Is it possible? I am sure that it is, just want to check out whether someone has good ideas. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I have found something that might help me:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2420-Mapping-AngularJS-Routes-Onto-URL-Parameters-And-Client-Side-Events.htm

Comment: I tried clicking the side bar menu in JSFiddle, it does not seems to be re-rendered. And also, i tried clicking the browser "forward" "backward" history button, It is working too. Did you fix the issue? or You are facing some other problem?

Comment: It is re-rendered. To observe that set the breakpoint in $scope.templateUrl = $scope.templateId + '.html'; line of code and start navigating. You will see that the code stops in that line after each item click/browser history and the page is empty at the stop moment and then you continue the execution the page is re-rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I would put the navigation menu outside ng-view (so it doesn't re-render), but use ng-class in conjunction with location.path() to differentiate the currently selected item.  E.g.,

```
<div ng-controller="navCtrl">
  <ul ...>
    <li ng-repeat='item in navData' ng-class="{active:isActiveRoute(item.id)}">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Then in navCtrl:

```
$scope.navData = [
  {'id':'1', text:'lorem ipsum'},
  {'id':'2', text:'dolor sit amet'},
];
$scope.isActiveRoute = function(route) {
   return '/' + route === $location.path();
};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/kFCqc/)