# Changing the class in AngularJS using URL data

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the class of an element when I change the page and use location.path() or something to grab the relevant URL fragment.

I am using $routeProvider for routing. The fiddle doesn't properly show it, but it works fine in my code. The problem I am having is that it does not update when I load the next page.

This code picks up the url fragment I want:

```
$scope.locationPath = $location.path().replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
```

Here is a very simple JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/timothybone/kmBXv/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

will's answer is almost right; you have to wrap `$location.path()` in a function so it's executed on every digest, not just once:

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
  return $location.path();
}, function() {
  return $location.path().replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kmBXv/3/

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$scope.$watch($location.path(), function() {
  return $location.path().replace(/^\/([^\/]*).*$/, '$1');
}
```

Comment: I implemented this logic, but it still doesn't update without a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using $watch:

```
<li ng-class="{active:isActiveRoute('edit')}">edit</li>
<li ng-class="{active:isActiveRoute('list')}">list</li>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.isActiveRoute = function(route) {
   // I added '/' instead of using a regex to remove it from path()
   return '/' + route === $location.path();
};
```

See also [AngularJs: stateful client-side routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440876/angularjs-stateful-client-side-routing/13459608#13459608), which has a working fiddle.