# AngularJs $watch on $location.search doesn't work when reloadOnSearch is false

Tags: angularjs, listener, watch

My *routeProvider* for route has *reloadOnSearch* set to ***false*** :

```
 $routeProvider
     .when(
        "/film/list",
         {
          templateUrl: '/film/list.html', 
          controller: FilmListController,
          reloadOnSearch: false
          } 
          ....

  )
```

I did this because I don't want the whole controller to be reloaded after query string changes, but I still use it and the url looks like this: `film/list?sort=isbn&order=asc&offset=0`. Now whenever query string changes I want to call a function from my controller. So I tried to set up a *$watch* in the controller:

```
$scope.location = $location;
$scope.$watch( 'location.search()', function( search) {
        $scope.list();
 });
```

But this doesn't work. If I set *$watch* to watch changes of an individual parameter of a query string, then it works. But I don't want to set $watch for every parameter of my query string. The solution I use now is this:

```
$scope.location = $location;
$scope.$watch( 'location.url()', function( url ) {
    if($location.path() == '/film/list')
        $scope.list();
 });
```

So instead of watching for the search, I watch the whole url, and then I check if the path is the one I set in *routeProvider* to conditionally call the function. What I don't like about this solution is that I have to explicilty type the value for $location.path to be matched.

Can anyone suggest a better solution, and perhaps explain me why is *$watch* not working for *$location.search()* ?

Comment: Try wrapping location.search() in a function.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465690/changing-the-class-in-angularjs-using-url-data/13468121#13468121 for more info.

Comment: Do a deepwatch. Add true as 3. argument to the watch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS Search Change Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867772/angularjs-search-change-event)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can listen for `$routeUpdate` event in your controller:

```js
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function(){
  $scope.sort = $location.search().sort;
  $scope.order = $location.search().order;
  $scope.offset = $location.search().offset;
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that you HAVE to set reloadOnSearch to false on the route for $routeUpdate to be available.  I found this answer via google, and it took me a long time to figure out why $routeUpdate was not available at first. (it is in the docs, I just missed it).

Answer (score 109):

In case you don't use Angular's route resolution or you just want to know whenever $location changes, there is an event just for that purpose

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event){
        var url = $location.url(),
            params = $location.search();
})
```

Comment: this is the perfect answer. it resolved my issue. Is there any list of such global variables like $locationChangeSuccess ?

Comment: @RakeshBurbure You can look in the source code :) It could help :)

Answer (score 27):

Stewies answer is correct, you should listen to `$routeUpdate` events for that since it's more efficient.

But to answer why your watch isn't working; when you watch `location.search()`, you're watching if the reference that the search method returns is the same or not. And it will return the reference to the same object every time you call it, which is why your watch isn't firing. That is, even if the search parameters change, it's still the same object that is returned. To get around that, you can pass in true as the third argument to `$watch`. That will tell Angular to compare by value, not reference. But be careful when creating such watches, because they will consume more memory, and take longer to execute. So that's why you should do it like stewie said.

Comment: Great, this is really good explanation! I will accept stewie's answer then if you don't mind since he posted the answer earlier, although this explanation makes the answer complete.

Comment: the suggestion to use the 3rd argument to $watch (objectEquality) is a great tip.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867772/angularjs-search-change-event/14868586#14868586 as well

Comment: Great explanation.

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return $location.search() }, function(params){
    console.log(params);
});
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

Watch the change on `routeUpdate` like this in controller:

```
 $scope.$watch('$routeUpdate', function(){
     $scope.sort = $location.search().sort;
     $scope.order = $location.search().order; 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

**$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);**

watchExpression => should be either

1. A string evaluated as expression or
2. A function called with current scope as a parameter

So here, You should pass your first parameter as a function.

**JavaScript Example =>**

```
$scope.$watch (
                function () { return $scope.$location.search(); };
                function (value) { console.log(value); } 
              );
```

**Typescript example =>**

```
this.$scope.$watch (
                     () => { return this.$location.search(); },
                     (value: any) => { console.log(value); }
                   ) ;
```

This did work for me.