# how to trap angularjs route event when query string change

Tags: angularjs-routing

I have a angular route like /x?stage=list, I want to trap route change event when route is changed to /x?stage=details, I have try bind event "$routeChangeStart", "$routeChangeSuccess", however but they are not triggered when query string change. I understand that angular care about the part "/x" of route, so I think it make sense the route is not considered change when query string change. So my question, in angular how do I trap angular route event when query string change?

Thanks

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15095901/266795), you can bind to `$routeUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of having the same issue. Take a look at $locationChangeStart and $locationChangeSuccess. Not ideal, but, depending on what you want to do, it might help.